# Re-writing url - apache - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am migrating an existing website to a Codeigniter one so need a help with re-writing of the urls.

I need to map old URLs with new URLs so that people visiting site from search engine results get redirected to matching new URLs as otherwise they would get page not found errors.

Most of the old urls in this format e.g.

```
/page.php?id=5 or /page.php?id=180&t=78
/data.php?token=GH45LK
/faqs.php?k=98#section2
```

Their matching new URLs are

```
/page/5 or I will be happy with /page?id=5&whatever=xyz too
/data/GH45LK
/faqs/98#section2
```

This is my current .htaccess of CodeIgniter

```
# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I tried something like this after `RewriteBase /` line

```
RewriteRule ^data\.php\?token=(.*)?$ data/=$1 [R=301,L]
```

but not sure if I got that right as it's not working.

Could you help me getting it right? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule` does not work that way: it only test the *path* part of an URL. For all the other parts (domain, query string, ...), you need to use `RewriteCond` and the corresponding variable (`%{QUERY_STRING}`, for the query string/here).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /page/%1 [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)token=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^data\.php$ /data/%1? [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)k=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^faqs\.php$ /faqs/%1? [L,R=permanent]
```

And I think there is an error with `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` as you redirect on `http://`, not `https://`, this should result in an infinite loop.

Also note that the anchor (#section2 in your example), is not sent to the server (so it can't be rewritten).

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I have tested some I am almost there. Just trying to understand this expression - RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)token=([^&]+) .... RewriteRule ^data\.php$ /data/%1? [L,R=permanent] ... it redirects data.php?token=gh567 to data/gh567 but if there is data.php?token=gh567&t=12 then it redirects to data/gh567?token=gh567&t=12 ... which is fine. I kind of understood (?:^|&)token=([^&]+) this expression but would you expand on how it catches. (My understanding is that if token is after "?token=" or anywhere in query string e.g. "&token=" put that in %1 ?

Comment: Yes. I voluntirely written this first rule as this because I didn't fully understand what is the difference between /page.php?id=5 and /page.php?id=180&t=78 so it depends what you really want to achieve. Maybe two rules to handle this(these) case(s) might be necessary.